# Weird symbols after website scrape

Tags: php, mysql, parsing, scraper, storing-information

I'm able to scrape sites successfully and get the content I wan't but for most of them I get things that look like this

> But at Fitgeek itâ€™s not just about Keh, or her fiancÃ© and business partner Wing Liang, itâ€™s about building a community of runners and walkers.

and

> â€œI wanted to start a store where the point would be to help people in common circles,â€ she says.

How do I get rid of these?

Comment: The problem is that you're taking the contents using the wrong encode system.

Comment: How do I fix that? The information is inside `<p>` tags

Comment: Without showing us your code is not so easy to help.

Comment: In short: Figure out what character encoding the site uses and either use the same encoding or convert it to whatever encoding you're using. Here's the info you need: http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html

Comment: There are many different sites I'm pulling from. I can show you my code but how will that help/ what part would you need to see?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure but I think you can change the document's character encoding in "meta" tag. Try to change "charset" value to utf-8 or something else